# Redirecting .net Framework 4.5 MVC app to the /authorize Microsoft Oauth 2.0 endpoint to retrieve authorization code

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, oauth-2.0

I need help redirecting my .net framework 4.5 application to Microsoft Oauth 2.0 /authorize endpoint.

I can make everything work manually, for example I can go to the /authorize endpoint with all the necessary parameters, and it will redirect me to my app with the authorization code in the url. This is fine, however I am drawing a blank on how I can get my app to direct to the authorization endpoint where the user logs in.

For example:

- User goes to [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com)
- App redirects to [www.microsoft.com/authorize](http://www.microsoft.com/authorize)
- Get sent back to [www.myapp.com?code=23d2d](http://www.myapp.com?code=23d2d) with code

Everywhere that I see questions similar to this online, people are using .net core or .net framework 5. This is not the version I am working with, so I do not believe they are relevant to me.

So if anyone could help me out on actually sending my app to the endpoint where the user logs in for authorization, please help.